# Possible bug in Close Queue?

Tags: bug

A while ago, I nominated a question for closure.  At that time, no one else VtC'd the question.  Today, someone else has VtC'd the question, so it is now showing up in the Close Queue.  However, I am unable to vote on it since I have already (a long time ago).

The queue should either not show this question since I've already VtC'd it, or it should allow me to re-vote on closing it (since my original vote has long expired).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, this is expected behavior. VtC votes age away, but you can only vote once.

Behavioral reason: it could be used to repeatedly apply a close vote over and over which would cause grief because "finally we found five people" ... bullying basically.

Technical reason: the table has a constraint on the value column ;-)

```
#Super simple example
UserId   PostId   VoteId   CreateDate
12345    55445    1        1/1/2001 12:00:00

#This isn't 100% accurate
VoteId   VoteDesc 
1        Upvote
2        Downvote
3        CloseFlag
4        ModeratorFlag
5        SpamFlag
```

For more details go play with data.se :D

Comment: should the queue not show me the question then?

Comment: _that_ may be a bug after all